# Corrupted or missing vector drawables after running Proguard

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I am working on application where i am using vector drawable mentioned below

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="100dp"
android:height="100dp"
android:viewportHeight="100"
android:viewportWidth="100">

<path
    android:name="curve_left_atrium"
    android:pathData="M4,48C4,22.6,24.6,2,50,2"
    android:strokeColor="#eb273f"
    android:strokeWidth="4"
    android:trimPathEnd="0" />
 <path
    android:name="curve_right_atrium"
    android:pathData="M96,48C96,22.6,75.4,2,50,2"
    android:strokeColor="#eb273f"
    android:strokeWidth="4"
    android:trimPathEnd="0" />
   </vector>
```

This works pretty fine in a debug build but its broken after running proguard in release build.

Version of design and appcompat libraries in gradle file are mentioned below.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Compile and build versions is

```
   compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
```

and to support vector i have done following in gradle.

```
   defaultConfig {

    generatedDensities = []

   }

   aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
```

and in proguard for design and support library i have done this

```
     -dontwarn android.support.v7.**
    -keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
   -keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

  # support design
 -dontwarn android.support.design.**
 -keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
 -keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
 -keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

 -dontwarn android.support.**
```

This issue is even opened here

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209558#makechanges

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: trimPathEnd put 1 than you take curve...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Er.Arjunsaini    but then how it works fine in debug build..??

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this line help me:
`-keepattributes LocalVariableTable`

Answer (score 0):

Hello i solved this problem myself. Actually i had to add following to proguard file

```
-keep class VectorPlay.** { *; }
-keep interface VectorPlay.**
-keep enum VectorPlay.**
```

and it worked.
Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: The `VectorPlay` class name seems random. Is this related in any way to one of the android support libraries mentioned on your question?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to the dexguard file to fix the problem:

```
# keep setters in VectorDrawables so that animations can still work.
-keepclassmembers class android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$* {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
-keepresourcexmlattributenames vector/**
```

(partly copied from https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209558#makechanges)